# How to push data in MongoDB's array with mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an empty array in MongoDB

And I want to push the Id in it.

```
router.put(
  "/like/:id",
  (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({ _id: req.user._id }).then(data => {
      if (data) {
        Post.update(
          { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) },
          { $push: { likes: req.user._id } }
        );
      }
    });
  }
);
```

This code is not working on how I achieve this.

Comment: `findOne()` in Mongoose returns a `Query`, not a Promise. You need to chain the `exec` method for you to get a promise i.e. `User.findOne({ _id: req.user._id }).exec().then(...)` or `User.findById(req.user._id).exec().then(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
router.put (
  "/addlike/:id",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", {
    session: false
  }),
  (req, res) => {

   // use try-catch 
   try { 
    User.findOne({ _id: req.user._id }).then(data => {
      if (data) {
        Post.findOneAndUpdate(
          { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) },
          { $push: { likes: req.user._id },
          { "new": true, "upsert": true} }
        );
      }
    });
   } catch(err){
    // handle error
    console.log('Error => ', err);
   }
  }
);
```

I have tested this in my local system ... working fine

Comment: When i am use this code my VS code give me some syntax error.

Comment: @RohitNishad  Do not copy paste whole code. follow  logic.
Use findOneAndUpdate


  Post.findOneAndUpdate(
          { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) },
          { $push: { likes: req.user._id },
          { "new": true, "upsert": true} }
        );

Comment: @RohitNishad You have solved this problem by using my logic. Am i right ???

Comment: No, i just change few things. like use $addtoset in place of $push and remove User.findOne etc.